# Numbers in Char

Tags: java, types

The question is very simple and noobish but It has troubled me for quite a long time.

If I want to store a number as a character in a character variable, I can do this with only the number 0 to 9, because these are specified in the ASCII table. 
But if I wish to store the number greater than 9, I can't do so directly.
E.g.

```
char ch='19';
int n=(int)ch;
System.out.println(n);
```

This gives me an error, at the very first line.

Is there any other way, by which I can store a number greater than 9 into a char variable?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: 19 is two characters.

Comment: pls read a basic tutorial on datatypes...

Comment: `'19'` consist of two characters `'1'` and `'9'`. You can't store both of these in a `char` variable. It is better to use `int` for your purpose. Why do you want to use `char`?

Comment: `char ch='19';` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: ***Please please please please PLEASE read _any_ basic tutorial or guide on Java datatypes...***

Comment: Maybe my short explanation helps you to understand what "char" is, and what it is not.

Answer (score 1):

'19' is not a char. a char is a single character.

You can store any number between 0 and 2^16-1 in a char variable. That value would represent some single character.

```
char ch=19;
```

Note that the character whose numeric value is 19 has no relation to either the '1' or '9' characters.

Comment: But it would be better to use a byte, short or int. Using char is obfuscating.

Comment: @laune Depending on the usage, a `char` would be appropriate here.

Comment: @laune That depends on how large is the number you want to store.

Comment: char is actually an integer type. It stores the 16-bit Unicode integer value of the character in question.

Comment: Unless you are doing something like ch - '0', calculations involving char aren't really good coding style. There's int, short, long,...

Answer (score 0):

A char has an integer equivalent namely its character code. You can store values up to 2^16-1 in a character, but you need to remove the quotes.  Simply assign integer value to the char.

Comment: Wrong. This is Java, not a native C-like language.

Comment: `You can store values up to 127 in a character` is wrong @1110101001.

Comment: @Qix Oh you were referring to that part. In that case sorry, you are right. Chars in java are 2 bytes.

Comment: @1110101001 Indeed! Kinda... They're not ASCII either; they're UTF-16 IIRC.

Comment: @Qix I agree with that.  However the comment `wrong` without further clarification was not very informative. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Storing numbers (for computations) in a char is almost always a bad idea. Consider this:

```
 char a = 100;
 char b = 52;                    // Output
 System.out.println( b );        // 4
 System.out.println( a - b );    // 48
 char c = (char)(a - b);
 System.out.println( c );        // 0
 System.out.println( b - a );    // -48
 char d = (char)(b - a);
 System.out.println( d );        // ￐
```

One does not store "numbers" in a char: it is (due to whatever historical or recently planned development) better called "enumerations of characters": Roman letters, digits, special characters, Greek letters, Cyrillic letters, CJK logograms and whatever, math symbols, diacritic signs, dingbats,... The use of ordinal numbers for this is due to the fact that computers store binary numbers.

```
char dig0 = '0';   // This stores the *character* we use as "zero". It has the ordinal 48.
char letA = 65;    // The character in let is what we call "capital A".
```

Storing the digits '0' through '9' by their ordinals 48 to 57 is not a good basis for computations.

Answer (score 0):

The Size of a Java char is 16-bit and the range is between 0 to 65,535. Also, the standard ASCII characters range from 0 to 127. So you should able to use 19 without the single quotations like **char ch=19**  instead of **char ch='19'**